# Unable to connect to docker postgres with password

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to connect to a locally running postgres on docker.
I am running the basic tutorial initialization:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

when I try: `pgcli -h localhost -U postgres postgres` I get password denied. I have also tried with pguser. I have also tried setting the username as well with the same result.

When I try with a generic database application, DBeaver, same result password denied.
I have tried going in to the running container and resetting the password as well: `docker exec -it <hash> bash` and then manually setting the password again to something simple.

Comment: You have to forward a port from local machine into the container and then connect to the forwarded port. If you are using the default port then you'll also need to stop the local postgres server only if installed, otherwise no need.

Comment: "password denied" is not a wording PostgreSQL would use.  Please quote the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error with port 5432 (default) and I had a local postgres installation too, which is creating the problem. To avoid the two instances fighting for same port, two things can be done.

1. Stop instance of local postgres
2. In docker container postgres path, open postgresql.conf and change default port.

Answer (score 0):

I faintly remember postgresql to
a) have a different password for a postgresql account than the one you have to set for the linux user account and
b) having to activate logging in with a username and password somewhere in the config

Hope this helps, just something off the top of my head

Comment: no such luck as I tried `docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=someuser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres` and same result with `pgcli -h localhost -p 5432 -U someuser postgres`